# How do I use the Dropdown component's searchQuery prop without breaking the display text?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am rendering a `Dropdown` component from `semantic-ui-react`. When I set the `searchQuery` prop, then the display text does not appear correctly for the selected option. Instead, it always displays the most recent query. I tried explicitly setting the `text` prop based on the selected value, but it still only shows the most recent query. How do I use the `searchQuery` prop without breaking the display text?

This code demonstrates the problem. Remove `query`, `setQuery`, `searchQuery`, `onSearchChange`, and `text` to see how it works (as expected) without the `searchQuery` prop.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const countryOptions = [
  { key: 'af', value: 'af', flag: 'af', text: 'Afghanistan' },
  { key: 'ax', value: 'ax', flag: 'ax', text: 'Aland Islands' },
  { key: 'al', value: 'al', flag: 'al', text: 'Albania' },
]

const DropdownExampleSearchSelection = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const text = countryOptions.find(o => o.value === value)?.text;
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>value: {value}</p>
      <p>text: {text}</p>
      <Dropdown
        placeholder='Select Country'
        fluid
        search
        selection
        options={countryOptions}
        searchQuery={query}
        onSearchChange={(e, { searchQuery }) => setQuery(searchQuery)}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e, { value }) => setValue(value)}
        text={text}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default DropdownExampleSearchSelection
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work if I clear the query when the user makes a selection. The `text` prop is not needed.

```js
onChange={(e, { value }) => {
  setQuery(undefined);
  setValue(value);
}}
```

Full working example:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const countryOptions = [
  { key: 'af', value: 'af', flag: 'af', text: 'Afghanistan' },
  { key: 'ax', value: 'ax', flag: 'ax', text: 'Aland Islands' },
  { key: 'al', value: 'al', flag: 'al', text: 'Albania' },
]

const DropdownExampleSearchSelection = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  
  return (
    <Dropdown
      placeholder='Select Country'
      fluid
      search
      selection
      options={countryOptions}
      searchQuery={query}
      onSearchChange={(e, { searchQuery }) => setQuery(searchQuery)}
      value={value}
      onChange={(e, { value }) => {
        setQuery('');
        setValue(value);
      }}
    />
  );
}

export default DropdownExampleSearchSelection
```